# Unable to add to text to ng2-canvas-whiteboard using context.fillText() and save it to the storage

Tags: javascript, html, angular, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using ng2-canvas-whiteboard and trying to add a component to add text. When I enable the canvas and add an input field, the input field shows up fine, but when I enter the text in it and press enter, the text doesn't show up on the canvas. Request someone to help me with this. Thanks in advance. Attaching the link to the code snippet that I'm trying out.

[Code Snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whiteboard-sbec9e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftext-box.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Findex.html)

I was trying to append the input element to document.body and once the text is entered and enter key is pressed, I was doing a context.fillText('xyz') and then removing the input box from the body. But this doesn't bring up the text on the canvas for some reason.
Also, if the text somehow shows up it is not saving along with the context.

TextBox Component:

```
    draw(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D): void {
    //console.log('Intial', context);
    if (!this.endPosition) {
      return;
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasWhiteboard'),
      font = '35px sans-serif',
      hasInput = false;

    canvas.onclick = function (e) {
      if (hasInput) return;
      addInput(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    };

    //Function to dynamically add an input box:
    function addInput(x, y) {
      var input = document.createElement('input');

      input.type = 'text';
      input.style.position = 'fixed';
      input.style.left = x - 4 + 'px';
      input.style.top = y - 4 + 'px';
      input.style.zIndex = '205';
      input.onkeydown = handleEnter;

      document.body.appendChild(input);

      input.focus();
      hasInput = true;
    }
    function handleEnter(e) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode;
      if (keyCode === 13) {
        drawText(
          this.value,
          parseInt(this.style.left, 10),
          parseInt(this.style.top, 10)
        );
        document.body.removeChild(this);
        hasInput = false;
      }
    }

    function drawText(txt, x, y) {
      context.textBaseline = 'top';
      context.textAlign = 'left';
      context.font = 'bold 18px Arial';
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.fillText(txt, x, y);
      context.strokeText(txt, x, y);
    }
  }
```

Main component Save to storage method:

```
saveToStorage(): void {
    this.buttonSave = true;
    // Get the current full update history
    this.iframeHeight = this.iframe.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    this.iframeWidth = this.iframe.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    const updates: Array<CanvasWhiteboardUpdate> =
      this.canvasWhiteboardComponent.getDrawingHistory();
    // Stringify the updates, which will return an Array<string>
    const stringifiedUpdatesArray: Array<string> = updates.map((update) =>
      update.stringify()
    );
    // Stringify the Array<string> to get a "string", so we are now ready to put this item in the storage
    const stringifiedStorageUpdates: string = JSON.stringify(
      stringifiedUpdatesArray
    );
    // Save the item in storage of choice
    sessionStorage.setItem('iframeHeight', this.iframeHeight);
    sessionStorage.setItem('iframeWidth', this.iframeWidth);
    sessionStorage.setItem(
      'canvasWhiteboardDrawings',
      stringifiedStorageUpdates
    );
  }
```

Comment: it is hard to look at the code via the link. Is it possible to include the relevant code in the question itself?

Comment: @ruud I have added some code above. Please have a look at it.